# Какой user agent используеться по умолчанию при отправлении запроса?

Tags: c#

Если не задавать в коде user agent и отправлять запрос без него, то какой юзер агент будет по умолчанию?

Comment: С помощью чего запрос отправляется? Вообще, user agent - это заголовок. Его может вообще не быть.

Comment: Запрос отправляю библиотекой Xnet, но можно и обычным WebClient. Вроде Xnet с помощью его работает. 
Просто делаю программы для ВК, и знаю если очень много раз была авторизация с помощью одного юзер агента ВК кидает аккаунт в блокировку. Так вот интересно если не указывать юзер агент, то по сути ничего по умолчанию не отправляется?

Comment: WebClient по умолчанию этот заголовок не добавляет. Насчет xNet нужно смотреть в документации к этой библиотеке.

Comment: Возьмите Fiddler или WireShark и посмотрите, что отправляется.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так узнать. Как то сам не додумался